# select arrow dropdown list in IE is different

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Select Arrow Dropdown list in Chrome is like this:

[image]

But in IE the select is like this:

[image]

How to fix this visual bug in IE, make it looks like Chrome??

Comment: That doesn't look like the standard dropdown style. Are you using a library to implement the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Every browsers will have their own dropdown arrow, you can still customize it using libraries.